# Core data fetch: Sort by relationship count

Tags: iphone, core-data, nsfetchrequest, kvc

I am trying to fetch an entity with the lowest count in one of it's relationships. The entity is called Solution, and this has a to-many relationship called gamesFeaturedIn which links to a Game object. So I am doing this (using the RestKit convenience methods):

```
Solution* lowestPlayedSolution = [Solution findFirstWithPredicate: nil sortedBy: @"gamesFeaturedIn.@count" ascending: NO];
NSUInteger lowestPlayedCount = [lowestPlayedSolution.gamesFeaturedIn count];
```

An this throws the error:

> 'Keypath containing KVC aggregate where there shouldn't be one; failed
>   to handle gamesFeaturedIn.@count'

I have found a few posts with similar questions several years ago. Maybe things have changed and the old posts don't give any definite answers to how I can do this without fetching all the objects into memory and performing the calculation manually. Anyone?

EDIT:
The core data store is SQLite backed, so I can not use transient properties to sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to break you the bad news, but things have not changed, at least in iOS5. There are mostly two workarounds, both rather non-elegant.

1. The one you mentioned, you do the sorting afterwards in-memory.
2. You create a non-transient property to store the count and update it each time you add or remove an item in the relationship.

Answer (score 0):

Create a transient attribute (relationshipCount) and an accessor for that attribute in which you return the count for that relationship. You can now sort on this attribute.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say this is an SQLite backed store. ie: can't sort on a transient property.